# I want to remove a number in the second brackets from a string value in all columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Agincourt North (129) ( 23.7%)
Agincourt South-Malvern West (128) ( 21.6%)
Alderwood (20) ( 25.4%)
Annex (95) ( 27.9%)
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Agincourt North (129) 
Agincourt South-Malvern West (128) 
Alderwood (20) 
Annex (95)
```

I am trying to use the str.replace function but am having difficulty with the syntax. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
de['Geography']=de['Geography'].str.replace('()','')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df['column2'] = df['column'].str.replace(r'\( [\d\.\%]+\)', '')
print(df)
```

Or this, this is will work only if the format is always `( 23.0%)` space after (:

```
df['column2'] = df['column'].str.split('\( ').str[0]
```

**Output:**

```
                          column                              column2
0               Agincourt North (129) ( 23.7%)               Agincourt North (129)
1  Agincourt South-Malvern West (128) ( 21.6%)  Agincourt South-Malvern West (128)
2                      Alderwood (20) ( 25.4%)                      Alderwood (20)
3                          Annex (95) ( 27.9%)                          Annex (95)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this to replace ( 23.7%)  with blank. It should replace any spaces(any spaces(float or int number %))any spaces with a blank.

```
df['Geography'].str.replace(r'\s*\(\s([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\%\)\s*','')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two syntaxes; one for strings and one for a regex match string.  Here are both versions:

String matching (done for each open/close parenth):

```
de['Geography']=de['Geography'].str.replace("(", "").str.replace(")","").str.strip()
```

Regex string version. Note the `r` preceding the literal indicates that it should be interpreted as a regex string (although in this case it won't matter):

```
de['Geography']=de['Geography'].str.replace(r"[()]", "").str.strip()
```

output:

```
0                 Agincourt North 129  23.7%
1    Agincourt South-Malvern West 128  21.6%
2                        Alderwood 20  25.4%
3                            Annex 95  27.9%
```